# get an special substring from NSURL string

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `NSURL` String:

```
NSString *url = @"http://ht21.easou.com/mty_ZhiQianQT.mp3?src=test&name=mty&size=100";
```

What is the quickest way to get the substring `mty_ZhiQianQt.mp3`?

Comment: Will you always have .mp3 files? If not, will always the substring you want to extract be after the domain and before the '?' character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ht21.easou.com/mty_ZhiQianQT.mp3?src=test&name=mty&size=100"];
NSString *name =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[url.pathComponents objectAtIndex:1]];
NSLog(@"%@",name); // mty_ZhiQianQT.mp3
```

just for your information :

`NSLog(@"%@",url.scheme); // http`
`NSLog(@"%@",url.host);  // ht21.easou.com`
`NSLog(@"%@",url.lastPathComponent); // mty_ZhiQianQT.mp3`

Comment: Although your solution will work for this specific example, it wouldn't work if the url was like `http://me.com/me/song.mp3`. So you could improve it by changing the call to: `NSString *name =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[url lastPathComponent]];`

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of methods for substring Nsstring. You can substring with range. Please refer Nsstring class reference for same.

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/nsrange-and-nsstring-objects.html

http://iphonesdkbasics.blogspot.in/2010/07/easy-nsstring-substring.html